# AWS sent me abuse report - apparently one of my servers was hacked - whats next?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hacking

I got an abuse report from AWS with the following information:
* Log Extract:
<<<
suspicious looking connections on the Undernet IRC
Chat Network connecting from a netblock you control ( 204.236.128.0/17 ).

Log taken at 2010.Oct.17 11:47:04 PM PDT

tomcat!~bacchus@204.236.250.XXX (Tampa)

[note- the address above is indeed of my server]
How can I detect what took over my server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your machine has been compromised and you didn't plan for that scenario then there's effectively nothing you can do. Reflect, repent, reboot, reformat, reinstall and restore your data only. Then apply all the vendor patches to bring your system up to current spec and harden your systems. Then learn how to use a host-based IDS effectively so you'll be able to recover more easily from any future attacks. Then carry out a careful review of the custom code /scripts you've deployed and try to make them more secure. Then maybe you can think about switching the service back on.